# Best way to solidify complex hard surface model?

Tags: modeling, topology

I am trying to model MP-40 and reached the part where I want to add thickness to the receiver (not sure how it called right) by adding a solidify modifier.
But after applying the modifier mesh had some inner overlappings, things like floating vertices, etc.

---

[image: one of the problems]

---

It seems not very convenient and I doubt the best way to clean it by hand.

**Questions:**

1. So isn't there a better way and or methodic to deal with such things?
2. I also tried the same with AK-47 receiver before and in order to deal with messed topology inside I
   cleaned and simplified it inside, is this acceptable and a good thing to do?

[Blender file](https://send.firefox.com/download/4c213e37bd7c65ea/#AkF-w7EjHT0rcL3iM6Bs1A)

Comment: Hello :). First - superbly prepared file. Second - Solidify modifier now has a *complex mode* which seems to work rather well for your mesh.